# Why do these models and methods crash my server/stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby-on-Rails and have been trying to slowly understand how everything works but I've run into a brick wall at this point.

I have the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :username, {:uniqueness => true, :presence => true}
   validates_presence_of :password_digest, :on => :create
   has_one :player, dependent: :destroy
   has_secure_password
   has_many :planets, through: :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :race, on: :create
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

In my UserController I create a User with login and password and that works just fine. Then I redirect to my PlayerController where I have a simple radio button to select race (just one right now) and then create the player and add it to the current user. That also works just fine. Now the problem is when I try to add a Planet into the player. I do this in the same controller method (not sure if this is proper but it needs to populate with a default planet to a new player).

```
def generate_attributes
    {
        class: 'HomeWorld',
        land: 500,
        ore: 100,
        agriculture: 0,
        industry: 0,
        housing: 10
    }
end

def create

    @current_user.player = Player.new(player_params)

    @current_user.player.planets.create generate_attributes

    redirect_to action: :home
end
```

On @current_user.player.planets.create generate_attributes my server completely crashes. Previously when I removed both belongs_to :user from player and belongs_to :player from planet I would get a Stack Level Too Deep exception.

There's obviously something I'm doing horrendously wrong but I can't figure out what it is. I attempted to debug but once I get to a certain point within the rails source code my debugger would disconnect and I'd have to force the server to stop.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised this code works?  Where do you assign `@current_user`? If you've redirected to a new controller (PlayerController) from another controller (UserController) the instance variables are essentially all lost.  I don't know why `@current_user.player` didn't generate a "method missing for Nil:Nilclass"

Comment: Is one of the fields on `Planet` really called `class`?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn sorry that isn't the complete code. I have another method in ApplicationController that runs with a before_filter and checks if logged in and fetches the User.

Comment: @DylanMarkow Yes it is... Let me check if changing it fixes it though I suspect it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `generate_attributes` method, it looks like you might have a field called `class` on your `Planet` model. This is almost definitely causing your problems, and you need to use a different name than `class`.

The reason is that in Ruby, just about everything has a class, e.g.:

```
>> "foo".class
# => String
>> User.first.class
# => User
```

However, for your `Planet` model, `class` is being set to a string. Rails uses a **lot** of introspection into class names to deal with associations; because you're linking this `Planet` to a `Player` with a `belongs_to`, I'm assuming Rails is checking the class of the `Planet` object to make sure it's correct, seeing `"HomeWorld"` instead of `Planet` like it expects, and raising an exception as a result.

(And even taking associations out of the picture, you'll still invariably run into problems using `class` as a field name).

Comment: That fixed it. I should have known better. Thank you for the help.